# Bluetooth on Android: Debuging startDiscovery()

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-device-discovery

I'm working on an app that searches for discoverable devices and displays them as buttons.
When calling `startDiscovery()` I would say it works 30% of the time, based on the way I'm currently debugging it, with the `BroadcastReceiver` and `ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED`.

I'm also using `isDiscovering()` to test if the `startDiscovery()` function is called but it returns false.

Is there a way to know if `startDiscovery()` is called successfully? And can you identify something in my code that would make it not fail?

Obs.: I have both `BLUETOOTH` AND `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permissions.

Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);

        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                String Address;
                // When discovery finds a device
                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    Address = device.getAddress();
                    System.out.println("Found Address: " + Address );  //DEBUG
                            //Do something with Address
                } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                    System.out.println("Discovery finished");
                }
            }
        };

        // Register the BroadcastReceiver
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);    

        MainActivity.mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

        if (MainActivity.mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            System.out.println("Discovering...");  //DEBUG
        }

}
```

Although I have a few discoverable devices available, none of them trigger `onReceive()` with `ACTION_FOUND`

UPDATE: I went to "Scan" under Bluetooth Settings while the app was running and I could not scan for new devices. I disabled/enabled Bluetooth and returned to the app and the problem was resolved. I don't know if that indicates that the adapter is busy or halted somehow.

Comment: Could you please be more specific as to what is not working?
Keep in mind that `startDiscovery()` is asynchronous so when you ask the `isDiscovering()` it might not have started yet.

Comment: The `BroadcastReceiver` does not return anything after I `startDiscovery()`

Comment: Could you try to listen also for [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED](ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED) to verify that it's actually starting?

Also add a call to `cancelDiscover()` just before `startDiscovery()`. The docs for `startDiscovery()` say:
"so an application should always call cancelDiscovery() even if it did not directly request a discovery, just to be sure."

Comment: I have included `cancelDiscovery()` but its still happens periodically.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm this issue.

On some telephones you just need to disable/active BT. You can doit programatically with

```
mBluetoothAdapter.disable(); 
mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
```

On some telephones its not enough ( Samsung S5 ). To detect it, I use timer, and if on end of timeout the change of BT broadcast state (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED or BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED ) wasnt received => its sign that BT is not working. Actually I show dialog which propose to user reboot the telephone.