# Broadcasting a message via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcast

How can I broadcast a text message from device A to other devices via Bluetooth!

Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please refer this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45140098/how-to-send-receive-messages-via-bluetooth-android-studio?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thanks! but  I want to broadcast a message, not to send it to a specific device..