# Android Studio and Bluetooth---mission impossible

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to put together a little phone app that will take characters from an ExitText and send them out via Bluetooth.

Getting Bluetooth to work seems to have become an impossible task.  I have used Bluetooth before with other SDKs and it was simple.  I want to replace a program I wrote years ago using VB5 and Bluetooth.  It was simple and I had it working in a few hours.  With Android Studio I can't seem to find any simple way of using Bluetooth.

Not that there aren't any examples.  In fact there are TOO MANY examples.  Most seem to be for obsolete versions of Android Studio or have other problems making them impossible to implement in 3.2.1.  When I try, get so many errors I know I will never be able to correct them.  Others don't throw errors but nothing happens.  I don't know what all the code should do so debugging it is impossible.  Over the last week or so I have tried 7 different "examples" (as reported by Android Studio "recent" list) and can't get any of them to run.

I did find an example that says it does something similar to what I want.  It contains over 300 lines of code!  Does that seem realistic?

I guess what I am asking is, can somebody point me in the right direction?  Somewhere that I can see an explanation of what is needed and how to create it?

Sorry if this sounds like a rant but in many ways it is.

Things I have tried and that came close to working but don't:
BluetoothChat.
BluetoothhTutorial
SimpleBluetooth
and  [How to send/receive messages via bluetooth android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45140098/how-to-send-receive-messages-via-bluetooth-android-studio)

Thanks

Pete

Comment: Just get started using google's bluetooth sample - https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt

Comment: @edwin OP is looking for Bluetooth Classic rather than Bluetooth LE.

Comment: Android Bluetooth has always been a problematic area due to differences in device implementation. It would be better to actually explain how you are testing (PC bluetooth, Android bluetooth, Raspberry Pi HAT, other device) and explain where you are stuck. Also realize that permissions around Bluetooth has evolved over time i.e. [Why do I need to turn on location services to pair with a Bluetooth device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/160479/3573) so older samples may be missing items. Check issues section if on github.

Comment: Morrison, yes I want the classic Bluetooth.
As for what I am doing.

I have a marque sign that I put out in front of the house for holidays like Halloween, Christmas, etc.
It displays any scrolling message on a grid of about 250 LEDs.  These are bright white LEDs creating 7 inch high characters that can be seen from quite a distance.

The first version I build was back in 1985 and used incandescent lights cut from Christmas light strings .  To drive it I used my Atari 800 computer and sent 16 control lines out the 4 joystick ports on a 34 conductor ribbon cable.

Comment: LENGTH RESTRICTION  The ribbon cable snaked across the living room, down the hall, over the door, across the porch ceiling to the marque that hung from the porch roof.  Over the years I have made many improvements including LEDs, embedding an Atmel processor in the marque and, in 2012, using just Bluetooth to send the messages to the marque.

Comment: LENGTH RESTRICTION No more cable of any kind.  The Bluetooth interface to the Atmel is a HC-06.  A small circuit board that all the Arduino people use. 

I wrote a program using Visual Basic to control the marque from a windows computer.  (Back then they still called them "programs" not "apps").  Basically it allowed the user to select the Bluetooth comport, Type a text message in a textbox, click send, etc.  There is additional functionality like saving messages, retrieving messages , controlling the scroll rate, setting test patterns, etc.

Comment: LENGTH RESTRICTIONS I just want to replace that windows Visual Basic program with an app on an android phone.

I have written Java programs for windows computers but I have to admit I am a bit rusty on the "workings" of Java so that may be some of my problem.

I think my main problem is I thought I could just copy someone's Bluetooth code into my app and be off and running.  That may have been a major mistake of mine.  I think I need to research Bluetooth and write my own code rather then copy what someone else wrote.

Comment: LENGTH RESTRICTIONS Then I will have to debug only what I wrote not what someone else created.
I think this falls into the category of, "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day.  Teach him how to fish and you feed him for life."  I need to learn to"fish". 

I think I will start with:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth
and follow the links from there.

Comment: LENGTH RESTRICTIONS If you have a better starting point, I'm all ears.

Also, I seem to have problems debugging on a phone.  Breakpoints and stepping don't seem to work like I think they should.  I have starting inserting "Toast" to try to follow the execution.

Right now I have "dumbed down" the problem to just getting two android phones to transmit back and forth using:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45140098/how-to-send-receive-messages-via-bluetooth-android-studio

No luck so far

 

Thanks
Pete

Comment: 1. You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52998269/edit) this question with your additional info (no length restriction) or 2 delete & create a new question with what you are trying with two android phones (list make, model and version of OS) along with any sample reference & where you are stuck, also use logcat to echo out where the program flow is.

Comment: I need to request a "Time out".  I have found I have a whole lot of things to do to clean up my app and my act.  I am finally getting to understand logcat and hoping I can ignore errors from other applications.  Like, "2018-10-27 11:48:25.959 903-9093/? E/vendor.qti.bluetooth@1.0-wake_lock: Release wakelock is released"  I will try to understand the app better.  That may require new questions.  I will post back here with (hopefully) how this was resolved.